# How to serve .mbtiles (vector tiles) and use them in web application?

Tags: web-applications, openmaptiles

I have downloaded maps covering Europe from OpenMapTiles. I want to use these .mbtile files (vector tiles) in a web application made with Leaflet or Mapbox.

How do I have to serve the .mbtile files so that I can use them in a web application? Do I need to serve them via GeoServer, TileServer? Or can I store the file locally and use this file?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I found, there are two ways:

- [Openmaptiles tiles server](https://github.com/openmaptiles/openmaptiles/blob/master/QUICKSTART.md#check-tileserver) that will server tiles generated on the fly from the mbutils. You'll need either a backend to run the tile server, or you can do it with serverless.
- Using [mapbox mbutils](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) to generate the Openlayers directory structure with x y and z.
  Mbutils is very easy to use, takes a .mbtile file and output the folder directory that you will be able whereever you want, like a AWS S3 bucket, served by AWS Cloudfront.
  Just be careful, when generating tiles from openmaptiles mbtiles with mbutils, generated files are gzip encoded, you have to serve them with a gzip content encoding (you can do this with S3).